# Not able to connect to AD LDAP on linux server : PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, linux, ldap, adldap

I am using AD LDAP authentication code to connect my web portal to SSO but I am unable to do so as it is giving me the error below.

The same code when tried on the windows server is working fine.

Is there any specific permissions that need to be provided in a Linux server?  The ports required for the end to end connectivity (389 and 636) are open and have been confirmed, still the LDAP is not able to connect.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'adLDAPException'
```

with message:

```
Bind to Active Directory failed. 
Check the login credentials and/or server details. 
AD said: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Please suggest what can be done to run the LDAP code for SSO authentication.

Comment: Does the linux server have access to the AD server? Are the credentials correct?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is make sure *ANY* LDAP client program can successfully connect to the A/D server from Linux.  I've found this Java tool helpful: https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/cool_tools/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282/.  Once you've successfully connected (using any Linux tool that's convenient for you), then make sure you have the same authentication and configuration for PHP.  See also: https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Networking/Single_Sign_On/Troubleshooting.html (note Wordpress == PHP).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Yes the credentials are correct as they are already in use on some other VM.

Comment: @Anshika Mendiratta, Plz post the code which you have tried.